# javax.persistence.EntityManager not inserting things in database even when outside of the rollbacked transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I don't understand why my code acts a curtain way so it would be awesome if someone could explain. The problem I am facing... I have 2 tables. As soon the method starts I insert something in "table1", **after** the inserting I start the transaction. Let's assume that code flow will always reach transaction.rollback(). I expect for the second query to be rollbacked, but not the first one. But it seems to me that both of them are rollbacked.

**TLDR;**

Expected result:

- First query is commited
- Second query is rollbacked

Current outcome:

- First query is rollbacked
- Second query is rollbacked

```
//Relevant imports
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;

public boolean myMethod(String createdBy) {
        final Long messageId = ((BigInteger) myEntityManager.createNativeQuery("insert into table1(created_by) values (:createdBy) returning id")
                .setParameter("createdBy", createdBy)
                .getSingleResult()).longValue();

        Session session = myEntityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {

                String sqlInsert = "insert into table2(messageId) values (?)";
                try ( PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert)) {

                    for (Object[] row : unsentRecords) {
                        pstmt.setLong(1, messageId);
                        pstmt.addBatch();
                    }
                    //Execute batch
                    int[] sqlStatmentsStatuses = pstmt.executeBatch();
                    //check if some statement failed
                    //Let's assume it always fails,just to be explicit
                    boolean somethingWentWrong = atLeastOneFailed(sqlStatmentsStatuses);
                    somethingWentWrong = true;
                    if(somethingWentWrong){
                        tx.rollback();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE: I don't know how to accurately call this question. So if someone can suggest a better title for the question put it in the comment and I will change it.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `messageId`? Generally, you can only retrieve data outside a transaction. To persist or update data, you need an active transaction

Comment: Yes, messageId is being increased each time I reach the function. The sequence table is being increased as if the data is being inserted, but the table that holds the data (table1) has no new data.

Answer (score 0):

Below is Transaction#beginTransaction javadoc

```
Begin a unit of work and return the associated Transaction object. If a new underlying transaction is required, begin the transaction. Otherwise continue the new work in the context of the existing underlying transaction.
```

It says create begin new transaction if not available. In you case, you are already executing one query which is starting transaction. So when you say `session.beginTransaction()`, it's not creating new transaction but returning existing transaction and that's why when you do rollback on that transaction, both queries are getting rolled back.

Comment: How can a transaction be started on its own. I thought that by default (if I don't say beginTransaction()) it would be one query one transaction (that query would be auto-commited)

Comment: How are you creating EntityManager instance? Is this created and managed by container?

Comment: I am using @javax.persistence.PersistenceContext annotation. So I guess it is managed by container

Comment: In that case, when your first query is executed, I think container is creating transaction and associating it with entity manager and next time when you do session.beginTransaction(), it's returning the same transaction. You can find more explanation here https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional